# Release task object after creating new Task object in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to create new task by clicking on Userform button with the following code:

```
Private Sub CreateTaskCMD_Click()
    
    Dim oTask As TaskItem
    Dim SelFolder As Outlook.Folder
    
    Set oTask = Outlook.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
    
    Set SelFolder = ObjNS.Folders(1).Folders(TaskFoldersList.List(TaskFoldersList.ListIndex, 1))
    
    With oTask
        'include time and from in subject of task
        '.Subject = ""
        '.Body = ""
        .StartDate = Date
        .Save
        .Move SelFolder
        .Save
        .Display
    End With
    
    Set SelFolder = Nothing
    Set oTask = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

The code gets the folder number from a list which already updated.
new task is created and moved to the selected folder, but problem is when I see the task window I cannot rename, or make changes in that rather I have to close it and then reopen it.
I am receiving message `"The item cannot be saved because it was modified by another user or in another window"`

I have already release the `oTask` at the end of subroutine? don't know where I am holding that new task. or where I need to release it from?

Comment: Did you try to [.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/outlook.taskitem.close(method)) it?

Comment: Purpose of the `.display` is to, show the task to user, so that user can make changes and then save it by himself. if I `.close` it then it is useless to create new task with Userform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating in the default folder then moving, you can add to the non-default task folder.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CreateTaskCMD_Click()
    
    Dim oTask As TaskItem
    Dim SelFolder As folder
    
    Set SelFolder = 
Session.Folders(1).Folders(TaskFoldersList.list(TaskFoldersList.ListIndex, 1))
    
    Set oTask = SelFolder.items.Add(olTaskItem)
    
    With oTask
        .StartDate = Date
        .Display
    End With
    
    Set SelFolder = Nothing
    Set oTask = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As @niton points out, you really need to use `MAPIFolder.Items.Add` instead of moving. But if you move, keep in mind that `Move` is a function that returns the new item, not a sub:

```
set oTask = oTask.Move(SelFolder)
```